# Vuetify - Adding v-menu to the v-card changing the v-card width

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

**Vuetify: 1.5.4**

I created simple v-card under v-flex, so it will automatically adjust based on screen resolution. And i have a v-list inside v-card to display some information.

[`Example`](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aMJvmQ?editors=1010)

In the above example there are 3 cards,
First card does not contain any menu, Second and third card have `v-menu` options, and `v-card` has `v-list`.

The problem here is the second and third cards are overlapped, because of the big title, but in the first card it was trimmed of. If i use `v-menu` it is not trimming off.

My previous version which i have used is 1.1.4 and it worked.

Any changed which i have to do? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the activator menu display to block

```
.v-menu__activator {
  display: block !important;
}
```

[Demo here](https://codepen.io/ittus/pen/oVZLBR)